# Adding provisioning profile from different team to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, mobileprovision

I have developed an iOS for my client using my developer account where I manage the provisioning profiles and certificates etc. and that account is linked to xcode.
However, my client wants to deploy the app using their provisioning profile.

They do not want to add me to their development account, because I am doing a freelance project and they dont want me to have access to their other apps.

They sent me an adhoc and distribution provisioning profiles (.mobileprovision) they created through their developer account. They instructed me to add the provision profiles to my keychain and then I would be able to use it.

However, when I try to deploy the app I get the following error:
**No provisioning profiles with a valid identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found**

Is it at all possible to use provisioning profiles that are not associated with my developer account?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi

They don't need access you to iTunes Connect, by adding you as a developer they don't authorize you to login in itunes connect.

Comment: I know if you upload an app to testflight you can upload a new provisioning profile after you've uploaded the app. I'm not really sure if that would work but it might be worth a shot

Comment: i think you want to take development certificate from their and use same distribution Certificate for the project.